# How to iterate a pandas column to get POS Tags

Tags: python, pandas, pos-tagger

I have a Panda Dataframe with German Reviews. I would like to get POS Tags and I found the pattern lib, which supports the german language.

Right now, I would like to iterate the Review column, to get all POS but I get following Error (with this code):

How to iterate a pandas column to get POS Tags

Code:

```
r['POSTags'] = parse(r['German_Reviews'].apply(split))
```

Error Msg:

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I would like to have following Output:

```
[(Das, DT), (Essen, NN), (war, VB), (lecker,..
```

Does anyone knows how I can solve this with the pattern library?

My DF Series looks like this:

```
Rating | German_Reviews           | Device ...
----------------------------------------------
5.0    | Das Essen war lecker     | Mobile ...
1.0    | Die Pizza war grauenhaft | Desktop ...
4.0    | Das Restaurant war ok    | Mobile ...
```

Comment: And how does your data in dataframe looks like?

Comment: I added it in my post

Comment: What is `split`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this works for your case:

```
import pandas as pd

'''
Rating | German_Reviews           | Device
5.0    | Das Essen war lecker     | Mobile
1.0    | Die Pizza war grauenhaft | Desktop
4.0    | Das Restaurant war ok    | Mobile
'''

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep = '|')

df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()

com = ['DT', 'NN', 'VB', '...']

df.German_Reviews.str.split().apply(lambda x : list(zip(x, com)))
```

[image: final]